# How to get hour difference between two date variables in python

Tags: python

I'm using python 2.7.2. I'm trying to get the hours difference between two date variables which has result from MySQL query.

```
#!/usr/local/python2.7.2/bin/python                                      
import sys                                                               
import datetime                                                          
from datetime import datetime                                            
import MySQLdb                                                           
import MySQLdb.cursors                                                   
# Inventory db connection
db1=MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost",user = "root",passwd ="*****",db="inventory")
cursor=db1.cursor()                                                                                   
cursor.execute("select max(date_created) from inventory.inventory_details;")                                           
inv=cursor.fetchall()

# Remote Inventory db connection
db2=MySQLdb.connect(host = "remotehost",user = "root",passwd ="*****",db="inventory")
cursor=db2.cursor()                                                                                   
cursor.execute("select max(date_created) from inventory.inventory_details;")                                           
remote_inv=cursor.fetchall()

print inv
print remote_inv

d1 = str(inv)
d2 = str(remote_inv)
diff = d2-d1
diff_minutes = diff.seconds/60
```

Here output of "inv" is ((datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 13, 54, 7),),) 
output of remote_inv is ((datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 19, 17, 2),),)

I need to convert into format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S". I tried using str() and it is not helping.

Just help me to get the difference of two MySQL date variables.. I just want to know whether this can be do-able in python or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the difference can be more than 1 day, you should use `diff.total_seconds()`. I don't understand how the format is related to getting the hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `inv` and `remote_inv` are tuples of tuples, as you can see from your output. That is because `fetchall` fetches all rows in a tuple; and each element in that tuple is itself a tuple of all columns. Since you have only one row and one column in that row, you should be using `fetchone` rather than `fetchall`, and getting the first element of that:

```
inv = cursor.fetchone()[0]
remote_inv = cursor.fetchone()[0]
diff = remote_inv - inv
diff_minutes = diff.total_seconds() / 60
```

Answer (score 0):

what about `strftime` ?

example :

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

Comment: I tried using strftime but it says "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strftime'" ...Here i'm importing datetime but still it is not working...